# Hand Stand Poop

Tags: dogs, behavior, defecation

My Jack Russell Terrier poops with his rear legs and behind raised, usually sticking the poop to a tree or a wall. Any ideas why?

[image: JRT]

Comment: If your dog has been seen by vet, who ruled out medical issues you should update your question to indicate so.  It is unclear if you are asking about a medical condition, or healthy dog with a behavior issue.

Answer (score 4):

Is he retaining that pose for a long time (eg: 30sec - 1 minute), and perhaps whining a little? How long has he been doing this from?  Also are his droppings solid, firm and dry?  If so he maybe constipated. You should get him checked out by your vet. 
Constipation can happen if his diet consists too much meat (ie protein) and very little fibers, so check that.
Usually when dogs get constipated the best thing is to give them an enema with liquid paraffin. 
But anyway before you do anything consult your vet.

Answer (score 0):

Great photo!

Your JRT is male. Male dogs mark their territory as a part of their "normal everyday" behaviour. Marking territory is a mechanism dogs use to let other dogs know who they are and helps to create an hierarchy of sorts amongst dogs in a certain area, a residual primal behaviour from a time when dogs ran in packs and moved around a designated territory.

Placing poop on a wall or tree is another way for your JRT to leave his message for other dogs.

His acrobatics, although unusual, are his means of ensuring his message is prominent.

Unfortunately this also means his message may be more difficult to clean up.

I'd suggest your only concern should be whether cleaning up his poop is a problem. If cleaning up his poop is a problem, you might like to consider some ways to control this behaviour. Happy to elaborate.